# Double summation in Pyomo

Tags: pyomo

I'm just starting to use Pyomo and I've been unable to figure out how to code a double summation. 
Something like [**this**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7R5oN.png).

Can someone give me a hint? 
Thanks for your help guys!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume your model is declared like:

```
m = ConcreteModel()
m.C = Set(initialize=[1,2,3])
m.D = Set(initialize=['a','b','c'])
m.P = Var(m.C, m.D)
```

then either of the following would work for a double summation

```
sum( sum( m.P[c,d] for d in m.D) for c in m.C)
```

or

```
sum( m.P[i] for i in m.C*m.D)
```